# Finding the maximum row for each set of rows in 3D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, max

This is my first time asking a question here,,

Hello i'm new to Java and i'm having some trouble, I want to know how could i store the info that i got from the code in a 3D array so i can find the largest integer within a group of integers (i have a 3D array and i stored this :

**i want the sum for each row which i have and i want the largest number from each sum.
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Gr1

- 8 5 9 8 7
  5 6 8 7 6
  7 8 4 5 6
  9 5 4 6 8
  4 7 5 3 6

Gr2

- 5 7 4 9 3
  8 6 3 7 5
  5 2 7 3 4

Gr3

- 6 4 3 7 6
  8 7 9 6 9
  7 5 6 4 8
  5 9 7 6 7

Gr4

- 3 5 6 4 7
  8 8 7 8 9
  4 6 8 6 6

This is my code:

```
   public static void getMaxVotes(int[][][] votes, String[][] uniStud, int size, int size1, PrintWriter uniWrite) {

    size = size1 - 1;

    int sumStud = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < votes[size].length; i++) {
        int totalScore = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < votes[size][i].length; j++) {
            int[][] storeSumStud = new int[4][j];

            totalScore += votes[size][i][j];
        }
        System.out.println(uniStud[size][i] + " " + totalScore);

    }
}
```

Comment: "finding the maximum row from set of rows" ? What do you mean by "maximum row" ? What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: It you're using 3D arrays and 2D strings to store students and vtes, you're already doing somthing wrong. Java is an OO language. Define classes and use them to structure your information in a locical way. Naming variables size4, m1 or i0 makes your code even more unreadable.

Comment: @BaSsGaz  hi , I mean finding the row with the maximum integer , in 3d arrays there are row and rows and columns inside those rows , I want to know what is the maximum ineger inside the rows ,, like there are 4 types and for every type there is rows and columns and those rows and columns aren't the same in size,, Thank you in advance

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for your advice , the variables names are just for now for testing , I'll change it later

Comment: And in the meantime, you'll spend hours trying to debug your code and every time wondering every time what size4, m1 and i0 are supposed to be. Trust me, I program for more than 20 years, and You'll save a lot of time by picking good names from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped , I've finally solved this problem ,,

```
    public static void getMaxVotes(int[][][] votes, String[][] uniStud, int size, int size1, PrintWriter uniWrite) {

    int maxRow = 0;
    int indexOfMaxRow = 0;


    // Get sum of the first row in maxRow
    for (int column = 0; column < votes[size].length; column++) {
        maxRow += votes[size][0][column];
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < votes[size].length; row++) {
        int totalOfThisRow = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < votes[size][row].length; column++) {
            totalOfThisRow += votes[size][row][column];
        }
        if (totalOfThisRow > maxRow) {
            maxRow = totalOfThisRow;
            indexOfMaxRow = row;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" has the maximum sum of " + maxRow);
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As @JB Nizet, said, you should re-consider your variables naming, stick to [conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions).

Your code seems to be largely incomplete and astray from what you apparently want to do, from you comment, you said

> I mean finding the row with the maximum integer

, So here's an alternative code for that :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][][] votes = new int[1][2][7];
    votes[0][0][0] = 1;
    votes[0][0][1] = 5;
    votes[0][0][2] = 1;
    votes[0][0][3] = 6;
    votes[0][0][4] = 9;
    votes[0][0][5] = 3;
    votes[0][0][6] = 1;
    votes[0][1][0] = 1;
    votes[0][1][1] = 5;
    votes[0][1][2] = 1;
    votes[0][1][3] = 10;
    votes[0][1][4] = 9;
    votes[0][1][5] = 3;
    votes[0][1][6] = 1;
    getMaxVotes(votes);
}

public static void getMaxVotes(int[][][] votes) {
    int largestInt = -1;
    String largestRowIndex = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < votes.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < votes[i].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < votes[i][j].length; k++) {
                if (largestInt <= votes[i][j][k]) {
                    largestInt = votes[i][j][k];
                    largestRowIndex = "votes[" + i + "][" + j + "][" + k + "]";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(largestInt);
    System.out.println(largestRowIndex);
    return;
}
```

This code prints :

```
10
votes[0][1][3]
```

Comment: Hi @BaSsGaz , Your answer has been really helpful , but the problem is that i have more than 1 type, you wrote  int[][][] votes = new int[1][2][7] but n my code it's  int[][][] votes = new int[4][][] , votes[0][5][5] , votes[1][3][5] , votes[2][4][5] , votes[3][3][5] ,, Thank You

Comment: The method that I wrote handles `int[][][]` arrays, if you want to handle other types, you need to overload it, make a `getMaxVotes(TYPE[][][] votes)` that could find the max number based on those type. You didn't tell us the type and what it has, so we can't help you as you can't write one method that will handle all types of arrays.

Comment: Thank you @BaSsGaz for your time, my method handles integers but with a different size , yours is int[][][] votes = new int[1][2][7] ,, but mine is  int[][][] votes = new int[4][not the same for every array][not the same for every array]

Comment: @FerasRasheed It doesn't matter, I just gave an example, the getMaxVotes() method will handle any length no matter `int[4][2][6]` or `int[4][2][3]` or `int[X][X][X]`. It scans the whole array, however much `int`s it has.